# output is not showing for functions

Tags: python, pycharm

I am using pycharm all code are run and show below in window expect Functions.

When I write code run and debug it is not showing output. I write that code on pycharm:

```
def exponent(base, power):
    result=1
    for index in range(power):
        result=result * base
    return result

    print(exponent(4,9))
```

but it give me in below window:

```
C:\Users\Rameen\exponent\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Rameen/exponent/exponent.py

Process finished with exit code 0
```

it does not give any error and output both.

when i debug this it show :

```
C:\Users\Rameen\exponent\venv\Scripts\python.exe "C:\Users\Rameen\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py" --multiproc --qt-support=auto --client 127.0.0.1 --port 61607 --file C:/Users/Rameen/exponent/exponent.py
pydev debugger: process 1292 is connecting

Connected to pydev debugger (build 182.3684.100)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Your call to `exponent` is **inside the function** - indentation matters in Python.

Comment: Though the indentation is wrong, call is not inside the function since there is a return statement before that? @jonrsharpe

Comment: @SleebaPaul it's *unreachable*, but still inside the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the indents from print.
The interpreter thinks the print function is still part of your exponent function. :-)

In your code example, the print statement is never reached.

```
def exponent(base, power):
    result=1
    for index in range(power):
        result=result * base
    return result

print(exponent(4,9))
```